# Image not getting displayed in emulator

Tags: java, android, xml

I am implementing a simple page similar to any other app, a 'header image' and content below.

I've placed a wedhead.png file manually into all the drawable folders that I want to display.

[image: This is the thing i wish to implement]

The layout I wish to implement displays correctly on the graphical editor, but not on the emulator. The emulator comes out blank. Emulator is ARM CPU based.

**Emulator screen -**

[image]

Here's my code

**XML File:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.wwmk1.MainActivity" >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="160dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
      android:contentDescription="header"
      android:fadingEdge="vertical"
      android:src="@drawable/wedhead"
      android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The Main activity java file**

```
    package com.example.wwmk1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What place did I go wrong?
Please help. Thanks

Comment: try to change image in simple view with some color background, and see if it's seen ,if it not work  continue to think...

Comment: @chaim I Tried to place a smaller 200kb square PNG image, nothing changed

Comment: maybe you open your project in v7? and there are 2 layout.Be sure you're linking to the current.

Comment: I accidentally created a separate portrait layout which was left blank